# How to create directed acyclic lattice graph in python?

Tags: python

Hello I am looking for a way to create lattice graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrnhV.jpg) in python, Right now i am using networkx python library for its creation but facing complication while forming the lattice. I would like to have suggestions with respect to any better library or any better approch, which would help me creating [lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrnhV.jpg)

As a input, i have a function which generates combination of integers to give a list of tuples.

```
def lattice(*args):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import networkx as nx
dg = nx.DiGraph()

import itertools
# list of tuples and rdd

listofsets = []

for L in range(0, len(args) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(args, L):
        print(subset)
        listofsets.append(subset)
```

e.g:
`()
(0,)
(1,)
(2,)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 2)
(0, 1, 2)`

And would like to Generate lattice for respective input

Comment: Please provide input: what do you have, what do you want...

Comment: In this case, it could be worth using a more structured form of data, even if it takes a little more work to get it into a more useable format, would make the graph plotting much easier, have you considered a dictionary, containing the points and links between nodes? It might be worth thinking about. I'll try and come up with an answer using a dict as an example of what I'm on about

Comment: First all thank you for the reply @RichSmith and will be great if show me with dict as example, however as per your suggestion @RichSmith i tried using dictionary, as levels as keys and combinations as values  this how dict output looks like `{0: [()], 1: [(0,), (1,), (2,)], 2: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)], 3: [(0, 1, 2)]} ` , now when i am using this as input to graphs it is showing only four nodes `[0, 1, 2, 3]` the problem is i need to connect from node level 0 to three values of node level 1 and so on  till node level three to form the lattice. Any  suggestions?